# Requested resource not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit inn Jmeter tool

Tags: jmeter

While running web-services in Jmeter for post type script ,Receiving "413 Request Entity Too Large for post type request" in Jmeter tool.
It is working fine using postman tool .

Answer (score 0):

If you having different behaviour it means that you're sending different requests and it is not possible to state what's wrong without seeing Postman and JMeter configurations so I can only suggest using a 3rd-party sniffer tool lide [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) in order to "catch" the requests originating from Postman and JMeter, compare them, identify the differences and amend JMeter configuration so the request would exactly match the one sent from Postman.

Also be aware that if you can successfully execute the request using Postman you should be able to quickly and easily convert it to JMeter:

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/) (in case of HTTPS protocol)
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will create relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler(s) along with other elements like [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)